# How do I modify an object in an Emberjs controller, so that the view is updated?

Tags: ember.js

In my router, I do this:

```
connectOutlets: function(router) {
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet(
       'acquisitions', router.get('acquisitionsController').find());
}
```

The `AcquisitionsController` looks like this:

```
(function(app) {
  'use strict'

  var AcquisitionsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    all: [],

    find: function() {
      var self = this,
          pk = $('#object-pk').attr('data-value');

      var imageResource = App.Image.create({id: pk});
      imageResource.fetch().done(function(data) {
        _.each(data.acquisition_pks, function(value, index) {
          var acquisitionResource = App.Acquisition.create({id: value});
          acquisitionResource.fetch().done(function(data) {
            self.all.addObject(data);
          });
        });
      });

      return self.all;
    },

    remove: function(acquisition) {
      var self = this;
      var acquisitionResource = App.Acquisition.create(acquisition);
      acquisitionResource.destroy().done(function() {
        self.all.removeObject(acquisition);
      });
    },

    addDuration: function(acquisition) {
      var self = this;
      if(acquisition.duration === null) {
        acquisition.duration = 1;
        var acquisitionResource = App.Acquisition.create(acquisition);
        var obj = self.all.findProperty('id', acquisitionResource.data.id);
        if (obj !== undefined)
          obj.duration = 1;
        acquisitionResource.save();
      }
    }
  });

  app.AcquisitionsController = AcquisitionsController;
  app.acquisitionsController = AcquisitionsController.create();
})(window.App);
```

The `find()` and `remove()` functions work just fine, and my view gets updated.

However, when I call `addDuration` as an `{{action}}` from my template, although the function executes and the object is saved, the view is not updated.

I thought the view was somehow *observing* the `all` property of my controller, because I had set is the `content` of my outlet, and it looks like it is being observed when I add and remove items, but not when an item inside it changes.

How can I fix the problem?

## Edit

Here's a little explanation of what `addDuration` should do.

I'm using [ember-resource](https://github.com/staugaard/ember-resource), so instead of having a `model`, I have a `resource`, as follows:

```
var Acquisition = Ember.Resource.define({
  url: '/images/api/acquisition',
  schema: {
    id: String,
    date: Date,
    number: Number,
    duration: Number
  }
});
```

This allows seamless integration with my CRUD API, with the `fetch()` and `save()` methods of `ember-resource`.

Initially, the `duration` property is `null`, and in my template, I do:

```
{{#if acquisition.duration}}
  <tr>
    <th>{% trans "Duration" %}</th>
    <td>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="acquisition.duration"}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/if}}
```

Then I have a button to add the `duration` property, like this:

```
{{#unless acquisition.duration}}
  <li><a href="#" {{action addDuration acquisition}}>{% trans "Add duration" %}</a></li>
{{/unless}}
```

Because I'm checking for `null`, in the `{{#if acquisition.duration}}` block up there, initially, the `duration` `TextField` won't show up. So I'd like the user to click on the `Add duration` button, and that will have the effect of creating a `TextField`.

Ideally, the field would be empty, but for now I'm contenting with an initial value of `1`, just because I thought that would be easier. So in my `action`, I'm trying to update the current `acquisition` object so that the `duration` property is set to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused by your `addDuration` function. but it looks like you need to be calling `obj.set('duration', 1);` instead of obj.duration = 1.

Comment: I've added a big edit in which I explain the `addDuration` function and show more code. Unfortunately your proposal doesn't work, because `obj` doesn't have a `set` method.

Comment: The reason it wasn't working for me was that I wasn't using models, but just resources. I've written a model and hooked it up to the resource, and now the `set` method works.